# Using wrap and unwrap on resize event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have some jQuery to pass an image to a modal.  When someone clicks on a smaller image, it brings the image up in the modal.  The code itself works fine.  The problem that I'm having is with smaller screen sizes.  When the width of the screen is small, the image takes up the full width of the device and is actually larger than the image displayed in the modal. In these cases, I want to remove the anchor tag around the image, so that it is no longer clickable.  Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="imgpop" data-target="#image-popup" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="images/carbcalc.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</a>
```

I'm using jQuery `unwrap` to remove the anchor tag and I am using `wrap` to put it back.  The code works, but the problem is that I am performing the functions in resize.  When resizing, sometimes the anchor tag will be removed and sometimes it won't.  Other times, multiple anchor tags will wrap the image.

This is the jQuery that I am using:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() == 991) {
        console.log("991");
        $('section a.imgpop img').unwrap();
    }

    if ($(window).width() == 992) {
        console.log("992");
        $('section a.imgpop img').wrap('<a href="#" class="imgpop" data-target="#image-popup" data-toggle="modal"></a>');
    }
});
```

What I'd like to do is remove the anchor if the screen width is <992, and add it back in if the screen is >= 992.

The code works, sometimes.  I'll get values logged to the console on occasion, but it is not as often as it should be.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Edit:

Using suggestions below, along with a couple of my own tweaks, I have this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var img = $('section img');

    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        if (img.parent().hasClass('imgpop')) {
            $(img).unwrap();
        }
    }
    else if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
        if (!img.parent().hasClass('imgpop')) {
            $(img).wrap('<a href="#" class="imgpop" data-target="#image-popup" data-toggle="modal"></a>');
        }
    }
});
```

It works and rewraps the img tag with an anchor tag, but after that, the anchor tag no longer works the way that it should.  This is the code that I have for putting the correct image into the modal:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('imgpop')) {
        let img = $(this).find('img');
        let modal = $('.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body img');
        modal.attr('src', img.attr('src'));
    }
})
```

This event is being called when one of the images is clicked before reducing the size to <992.  Once I've reduced the size and then resized it to >=992, the event is no longer firing and I am not getting images in the modal.  I took a look at the HTML using Firefox show source before and after unwrapping and re-wrapping the images, and it looks exactly the same.

Any idea how I can fix this and finish off this project.

Comment: Use `< 992` and `>= 992` as your conditions

Answer (score 0):

You just need a check to happen.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
if ($(window).width() <= 991) {
    console.log("991");
if ( $('section img.img-fluid').parent().is ('a') {
    $('section img.img-fluid').unwrap();
}
}

if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
    console.log("992");
if ( !$('section img.img-fluid').parent().is ('a') {
    $('section img.img-fluid').wrap('<a href="#" class="imgpop" data-target="#image-popup" data-toggle="modal"></a>');
}
}
});
```